# how to use swiftReactive watching an method with some param when it use?

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

sorry my English not verywell,in swift i want to use SwiftReactive do something ,like in ObjectC the RAC work,like:

```
[[a rac_signalForSelector:@selector(xxxx)] subscribeNext:^(id x) {

}];
```

and in swift i learnd use :

```
a.reactive.trigger(for: #selector(a.shareWithConfiguration(type:))).observeValues { () in

    }
```

but i cannot get the param in this method ,yeah it's that named"type",try to write like this:

```
a.reactive.trigger(for: #selector(a.shareWithConfiguration(type:))).observeValues { (type) in

    }
```

but it did't work
please help me ,just show me how to get this named "type" value

Comment: and i found another quetion,in a viewcontroller use this method it's didnot work ,i set breakpoint but didnot run in here

Answer (score 0):

it's done buddy.  i have already fix it,reason is didn't write @objc dynamic before that method